# asp.net mvc c# enctype

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how can i add enctype **only** in

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

A form element *requires* an `action` and `method` attributes.

See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3):

```
<!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ -(FORM) -- interactive form -->
<!ATTLIST FORM
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  action      %URI;          #REQUIRED -- server-side form handler --
  method      (GET|POST)     GET       -- HTTP method used to submit the form--
  enctype     %ContentType;  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  accept      %ContentTypes; #IMPLIED  -- list of MIME types for file upload --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- name of form for scripting --
  onsubmit    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the form was submitted --
  onreset     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the form was reset --
  accept-charset %Charsets;  #IMPLIED  -- list of supported charsets --
  >
```

As you can see from the DTD fragment, the `action` attribute is **#REQUIRED** as is the `method` (`GET` or `POST`).

This is why `Html.BeginForm()` adds them automatically.

Answer (score 3):

As said, you need to also have the action and method specifid (BeginForm() adds this in for you anyway).

To add the encoding type, you need to at least use the overload which makes you specify the mvc action, controller and form method, like so:

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new{enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
```